# how I concat following two xpath and make a one xpath

Tags: selenium, xpath

I have two xpath

1. for select day: `.//*[@id='calendar']//*[contains(@class,'fc-first fc-last')]/td[4]`
2. for select time slot: `.//*[@id='calendar']//*[contains(@class,'fc-agenda-slots')]/tbody/tr[3]/td`

I need to concat both xpath and create a one and have to access a calendar slot with date & time.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJZWK.jpg)

I have attached my code in image format.

Comment: Never post your codes as image!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use | (union operator)

```
.//*[@id='calendar']//*[contains(@class,'fc-first fc-last')]/td[4]|.//*[@id='calendar']//*[contains(@class,'fc-agenda-slots')]/tbody/tr[3]/td
```

Comment: I have tried this code on command prompt using irb. Element is searched but not able to click on that block. After clicking each date & time combination slot, there is a one pop up window opened.

Comment: Is it proprietary application? Can you give me the full HTML or URL of the application? Clicking on elements depends on how the application handle 'click' event.

Comment: Instead of this union, i used > .//*[@id='calendar']//*[@class='fc-first fc-last']//*[contains(@class,'fc-wed fc-col3 ui-widget-content')]|.//*[@id='calendar']//*[@class='fc-agenda-slots']//*[contains(@class,'fc-slot3')]     And try to click then it works but not getting selected proper time slot.

Comment: @Pravin I think I got your point now. I think you cannot use union to solve this problem. Can you try this xpath? `.//*[@id='calendar']//tbody/tr[contains(@class,'fc-first fc-last')]/td[contains(@class,"fc-wed")]//*[contains(@class,'fc-agenda-slots')]/tbody/tr[3]/td`